# Unable to Creating Work Profile (Profile owner) in Some Android 5.0+ devices?

Tags: android, android-activity, profile, user-profile, device-owner

I am facing one problem and i am not getting solution on internet. My problem is- in some devices like samsung and motorola which have android 5.0+ version i am unable to create work profile(TestDPC app on playstore). What's the reason please if anybody know explain it please. 
This is the code checked by android at time of work profile creation-

```
  PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    System.out.println(" can create profile="+ pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MANAGED_USERS));
```

Is There an option to change that thing so that i can create a work profile in every device.

Thank you

Comment: I think you should update the app as the previous version is updated with a different package name

Comment: nop that's not a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking code

```
pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MANAGED_USERS));
```

if device has a managed user than only it can create a work profile otherwise won't allow to create work profile.Device should have this managed user feature.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons why a phone with Android 5.0+ would not support work profiles. The most common reason is too little ram. Google recommends a minimum of 1.5 GB of ram to support work profiles, but less ram may still work just with performance degradation.

I don't believe there is a work around for your situation, other than re-compiling the OS adding at a minimum the hardware feature android.software.managed_users. But obtaining the source may be difficult for a Motorola or Samsung phone.

In addition, the phone must not be configured as a low RAM device, i.e. ro.config.low_ram. And if only one user is supported, Google provides additional patches to support a managed profile for that single user. Google has much more detailed documentation for OEMs to implement an Android for Work device.

Answer (score 0):

Use the adb command

```
adb shell pm get-max-users
```

The Maximum Users depends on the Android ROM and the OEM of the device.

 For Samsung & Motorola devices it's generally

```
 Maximum supported users: 1
```

For a Xiaomi device (sweet) running MIUI ,

```
 it's Maximum supported users: 4
```